# Windows - Android studio open the project via shortcut

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

Is there a way to set a shortcut on windows to open a project on android studio automatically?
Example:

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 0):

There is no such shortcuts directly AFAIK. But you can always use this setting:

Settings -> Appearance & Behaviour -> System Settings -> Reopen last project on startup